# protractor getText() not being set to a variable

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm testing the ability of my admins to edit other users. The `user.firstname` model is what I'm checking. I want to be able to set the first name back to what it originally was after testing.

```
it("should be able to edit a different profile.", function () {
        browser.get('#/user/2');
        var fname = element(by.model('user.firstName'));
        var originalName = '';
        fname.getText().then(function (txt) {
            originalName = txt;
        });
        console.log('here');
        console.log(originalName);
        fname.sendKeys('New Name');
}
```

I haven't gotten to the`expect` part yet. Right now, I'm not able to get the current name (Bob) stored in a variable. It prints out blank:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
..............here

....
```

If I console.log inside the function, it prints out the proper name, but it looks like my promise is not being fulfilled until later?

```
        fname.getText().then(function (txt) {
            console.log(txt);
            originalName = txt;
        });
        console.log('here');
        console.log(originalName);
        fname.sendKeys('New Name');
}
```

gives me this:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
..............here

Bob
....
```

How do I get that value outside of the promise (via a variable)? Am I just doing it way wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, yes, you're doing it way wrong. The code inside the `then()` is executing after the code that follows it because the promise is fulfilled after the latter code runs. This is frankly one of the trickier parts of writing protractor tests.

There are a few possible solutions to this:

- Add your code to the `then()` block.
- Put your code in a subsequent `then()` block.
- "Wait" for the browser to do the work

So the first one is obvious, the second one looks like:

```
fname.getText().then(function (txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    originalName = txt;
}).then(function () {
    console.log('here');
    console.log(originalName);
});
fname.sendKeys('New Name');
```

The third looks like:

```
fname.getText().then(function (txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    originalName = txt;
});
// ... do stuff ...
browser.wait(function() {
    return originalName !== undefined;
}).then(function() {
    console.log('here');
    console.log(originalName);
});
fname.sendKeys('New Name');
```

Also noteworthy here, this is only if you care about the `console.log()` business. You notice the `fname.sendKeys()` code is outside the block – protractor will take care of waiting for the last operation to finish regardless before doing the next one. Protractor will also take care of fulfilling the promises for you if you are using getText() within a jasmine `expect()`.

Comment: I ended up going with option 1 while I waited for your answer... I may end up refractoring to option 3, because it looks the cleanest to me.

Comment: I took about 6 hours to find an answer that solved my problem. This answer was extremely helpful! I can't understand why it has only 138 visualizations and 3 votes. Am I missing something? There are other good answers like this one that I wasn't able to find?